# How to check if a promise returns an empty object

Tags: angularjs

The goal is to check if the user is logged in. When the page is loaded, a promise is used to check the current user. If the user is not logged in, the server returns `{}`. My problem is that I don't know how to check if the promise returns the empty object `{}`.

I defined a resource:

```
myapp.factory('User', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/users/:userId', {userId: '@id'}, {
    current: {method:'GET', params: {userId: 'current'}}});
});
```

which is used in a resolve property in ui-router. The resolve is used to provide data to my controller.

```
resolve: {
    user: ['User', function(User) {
        return User.current();
    }]
},
controller : function($scope, $window, user) {
    $scope.user = user;

    $scope.userLoggedIn = !isEmptyObject(user);

    function isEmptyObject(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        var name;
        for (name in obj) {
        return false;
        }
        return true;
    }                                   
}
```

The express server side is defined as:

```
app.get('/users/current', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    console.log(req.user);
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
        res.send(req.user);
    } else {
        console.log("Not Authenticated");
        res.send({});
    }
});
```

The issue is that the `isEmptyObject` function always returns true.

Comment: You are resolving `User` but injecting `user` in the controller (which will be `undefined`)?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to return a property in object from server like `{notLoggedIn:true}`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    function isEmptyObject(obj) {

       if (obj.length && obj.length > 0)
           return false;          

       if (obj.length === 0)
          return true;           
    }
```

BTW, [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/) plugin has own method:

```
isEmpty_.isEmpty(object)
```

Returns `true` if object contains no values (no enumerable own-properties).

```
 _.isEmpty([1, 2, 3]);
 => false

 _.isEmpty({});
 => true
```

Comment: this is incorrect answer, function `isEmptyObject` returns undefined for both, empty and non-empty object